# Magento 2: How to validate the cart rules?

Tags: magento2, price-rules, class

I need to develop a function in the cart rules.

Basically it is to check the amount that is added in the cart and apply a fixed price to the product.

I have in mind how to apply the logic. But I need to see the functionality of magento to observe the cart and be able to validate this rule.

I know it's the SalesRule extension but I can not find the correct classes.

Answer (score 3):

You have to check `Magento\SalesRule\Model\Validator`. This is the main class from where validation is checking.

Rules validator classes are exits at

`Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition`

Rules render  at admin from `Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Combine`